# Creating multiple lines inside a nodule of a binary graph in the r package igraph

Tags: r, igraph, treenode

Package: igraph
Program: R-gui
System: Windows 8
Problem: How does someone put text, within a node, onto multiple lines instead of the default one line?
Background: Using reingold layout with a Binary Tree graph. When I print original tree the text for levels 5+ tends to mesh together into an incoherent mess. Right now I am putting the tree into a png file with, relatively, insane dimensions so it can be read easily. I am looking for a solution so I can move the text onto multiple lines to increase the font size and decrease overall dimensions.

Pertinent Code:

## creating tree

```
library(igraph)
BinaryGraph<-graph.tree(n = 1)
```

## filling tree, where NewName is variable containing all the gene locations at the specific node location

```
LeftHolder = NewName[j]
BinaryGraph <- BinaryGraph + vertices(LeftHolder)
BinaryGraph <- BinaryGraph + edge("Root" , LeftHolder)
```

## plotting

```
V(BinaryGraph)$label.cex = 0.65
png(file = "f:/Current Work/PrunedTree.png",width= 60, height=40, units="in", res=300)
plot(BinaryGraph, vertex.size=10, edge.width=2 ,layout = layout.reingold.tilford(BinaryGraph, root = "Root"))
polygon(c(4.5,5.5,5.5,4.5),c(-60,-60,50,50),col="#0000ff22")
dev.off()
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example